# Getting KeyError when calling self controller.method() in a tkinter app

Tags: python, tkinter

I have built a multipage `tkinter` app. The app is structured so that the main GUI is stored in one `.py` file and the other pages stored in a `dict` within the main app. the main app is referenced as `self.controller` in each of the pages.

When I try to use a method from the controller, some times it produces a KeyError and sometimes it doesn't and for the life of me I can't figure out why.

I have rewritten this set of pages a lot based on answers provided by the community and each time I do it fixes a problem but it still hasn't solved the issue I'm trying to solve (passing info between pages"

the code below is my main app (I'll blackify the code later)

```py
import tkinter as tk
from front_page import FrontPage
from main_page import GamePage



class GUI(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        container = tk.Frame(self)

        # Initialize Window
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)


        #Initialise each page
        self.frames = {}
        for F in (FrontPage, GamePage):
            page_name = F.__name__
            frame = F(parent=container, controller=self)
            self.frames[page_name] = frame


            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.show_frame("FrontPage")#This one works perfecly




    # shows the desired frame
    def show_frame(self, page_name):
        frame = self.frames[page_name]
        frame.tkraise()


    def get_page(self, page_name):#I think the problem is actually here
        return self.frames[page_name]

app = GUI()
app.geometry("400x600")
app.mainloop()
```

now on the FrontPage I use a button push to configure a label on the GamePage
and that is where I'm getting the traceback. The implementation for this is:

```py
class FrontPage(tk.Frame):
    """This is a class to make the front page
    it inherits from tk.Frame
    """

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller

        self.mainframe = tk.Frame(self)
        self.mainframe.pack(expand=True, fill=tk.BOTH)

        (...)

        gamepage = self.controller.get_page("GamePage")#this is the problem
        self.forward_label = gamepage.name_label
        #when I comment out these lines everything else works

    def on_button(self):
        self.output_frame.configure(text = self.name_entry.get())
        self.forward_label.configure(text = self.name_entry.get())
```

this code produces the traceback

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "/Users/kevinomalley/Desktop/python_work/rapid_rpg/app_GUI.py", line 50, in
>
> app = GUI()
>
> File "/Users/kevinomalley/Desktop/python_work/rapid_rpg/app_GUI.py", line 22, in **init**
>
> frame = F(parent=container, controller=self)
>
> File "/Users/kevinomalley/Desktop/python_work/rapid_rpg/front_page.py", line 106, in **init**
>
> gamepage = self.controller.get_page("GamePage")
>
> File "/Users/kevinomalley/Desktop/python_work/rapid_rpg/app_GUI.py", line 40, in get_page
>   return self.frames[page_name]
>
> KeyError: 'GamePage'

I have no Idea why I can call the `controller.show_frame('')` method without issue, but the `controller.get_page('')` method returns the keyerror.

Help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to reference the page "GamePage" before it has been created. That is because you placed the code in `FrontPage.__init__`. You can't reference a page before it has been created.

Comment: Thank you for the answer again Bryan. I have moved the code around a bit, I'm still not getting the functionality I'm actually looking (taking user input and passing it to label on GamePage) but your answer has fixed the trace back.